# How to have dynamic data on webpage using Django models?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

(I am a django beginner)
I have a requirement where the dropdown menu using Django models in my webpage needs to have live/dynamic data from a third party server.

For eg. current models data is emp1,emp2 but if the third party server adds emp3, then I should be able to display emp1,emp2,emp3 in my webpage when a user refreshes the webpage.

How can I achieve that using django models?
(I know we can do this without Django models by making an ajax call directly from the webpage, but I can't do so because of security restriction so I have to fetch this data in the backend, and with Django models currently I am only able to get the data in my database once when the server is started and NOT when the third party server updates its database).

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to this specific situation that I was stuck in. I will try my best to answer this here so that it can be helpful to someone else:

My problem code earlier in my `views` function:

```
for key in sorted(myvar):
            value = City(name=key)
            value.save()
            for items in myvar[key]:
                value2 = Country(name=items,site=value)
                value2.save()
```

So the above code is basically updating my models called City and Country from the data stored in myvar variable.

However, I was updating the models every single time the page loads (so that the models has the latest and most up to data data). But that made the models data inconsistent when multiple users are using the webpage. For eg., when user A loads the webpage, he or she gets some content, now when user B loads the webpage, he or she gets some other content because my views.py has updated the models with the latest data available in `myvar`. This is not a problem for the user B but it is a problem for user A which is relying on the older models data which doesn't exist any more.

*How I solved this problem*:

By checking if the data I am adding already exists or not in the models, I will update my models ONLY if the data doesn't exist (I am verifying this using the `.exists()` function).

```
for key in sorted(myvar):
    if City.objects.filter(name = key).exists():
        pass
    else:
        value = City(name=key)
        value.save()
        for items in myvar[key]:
            value2 = Country(name=items,site=value)
            value2.save()
```

This way, at least, the models data will get updated ONLY when there's a need to update the models based on the new content in `myvar`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Dharman

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, it was in two parts. Please note that we aim to have as little noise as possible on Stack Overflow. This includes comments. I understand you want to be nice, but there's no need for this here as we try to keep it entirely professional. I will delete these two comments in a few minutes.